# Contents of message not displayed

Tags: sendmail

I tried to send a pdf file via email. My attachment files were successfully sent, but the contents of the message cannot be displayed ***(mainmessage = Hi, here's the file.)*** . If I use phpmailer, file as attachment cannot be delivered but the message content can be displayed. This is the code:

```js
require("generate_pdf.php");



// Settings


$name = "John";

$email = "john@gmail.com";

$to = "$name <$email>";
$from = "Server@gmail.com";

$subject = "Here is your attachment";

$mainMessage = "Hi, here's the file.";
$fileatt = $path_file;
$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = $nama_file;
$headers = "From: $from";

// File
$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

// This attaches the file
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers. = "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n".
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n".
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n".
"-{$mime_boundary}\n".
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n".
$mainMessage.
"\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message. = "--{$mime_boundary}\n".
"Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n".
" name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n".
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n".
" filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n".
$data.
"\n\n".
"-{$mime_boundary}-\n";


// Send the email
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one hyphen before the body part so it is not displayed

Also the specification says CRLF, so you should use `\r\n` alwayw